# Passport.js does not authenticate SSR async request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, passport.js, next.js

I have setup `Passport.js` using the `local-stratagey`, with my express server.

When I am logged in and make an async request within NextJS's `getInitialProps`, it correctly permits the GET request via the client render but not the server side render. That is to say, If I access the private route via the client side routing, it shows the route and permits the aync request, but when I hit the page directly from the browser it permits the route but not the async request via the server side call of `getInitialProps`.

To add to the complexity, I am using Next.js and it's new api routes. I catch the route in server.js first to authenticate, and then if it's authenticated I pass it on the Next.

```
  // server.js routes
  app.get('/apples', function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log(`[${req.method}]`, 'SERVER - ROUTE AUTHENTICATED');
      return handle(req, res);
    } else {
      console.log(`[${req.method}]`, 'SERVER - ROUTE NOT AUTHENTICATED');
      res.redirect("/login");
    }
  });

  app.get('/api/apples', function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log(`[${req.method}]`, 'SERVER - API AUTHENTICATED');
      return handle(req, res);
    } else {
      console.log(`[${req.method}]`, 'SERVER - API NOT AUTHENTICATED');
      res.status(401).end();
    }
  });

// /pages/apples.js - the consuming page
Apples.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/apples');
  const apples = await response.json();
  return { apples }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread solved my problem: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/halp-nextjs-express-passport-next-api-routes~f5f60d4a-cfea-422b-8dfe-ed243b598ce6

The TL;DR is that if you hit the server directly, return the data you want directly from the server, rather than via a subsequent call to the api. The api request should only be used when you hit a page via client side routing.